# backgroundworker vs Event

Tags: c#, winforms

i am use my Winform application to send buffer of packet to my network card, my application show to progress via Progress Bar, if i choose to send all the buffer with out any delay between the packets my application stuck (become gray) and return to normal behaviour only after senging all the buffer (in case my buffer is very big, something like > 50,000 packets)
so how can i deal with such case ? maybee to change the backgroundworker who check all my class properties (number of packet send etc...) with event ?

```
    listBoxFiles.SetSelected(0, true);
    bgWoSingle = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgWoSingle.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    bgWoSingle.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgW_ProgressChanged);
    bgWoSingle.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    (s3, e3) =>
    {
        while (loopsCount < numberOfLoops && bContinuePlay && ifContinue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; (i < listBoxFiles.Items.Count) && bContinuePlay && ifContinue; i++)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    lbCurrentFileNum.Text = "(" + (i + 1) + "/" + listBoxFiles.Items.Count + "):";
                });

                string path = (string)listBoxFiles.Items[i];
                pcap = new Pcap(path, playSpeed, isSync);
                pcap._startTimer += new EventHandler(pcap_packetStartTimer);
                pcap._stopTimer += new EventHandler(pcap__packetStopTimer);
                pcap.evePacketProgress += new Pcap.dlgPacketProgress(
                    (progressCount) =>
                    {
                        pcap._fileSelectedIndex = i;
                        bgWoSingle.ReportProgress(progressCount, pcap);
                    });

                if (selectedAdapter != null)
                {
                    //play the file
                    bContinuePlay = pcap.playCapture(selectedAdapter._packetDevice);                     }
            }

            loopsCount++;
        }

    bgWoSingle.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
        (s3, e3) =>
        {

        }
        );

    bgWoSingle.RunWorkerAsync();
```

here i check the class properties (class name is pcap):

```
void bgW_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //check the properties and update the UI
    labelPacketSent.Text = pcap._numberOfSendPackets.ToString("#,##0"); 
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use BackGroundWorker for it. I am adding a small example for it.

```
private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(80, 15000);
}

private void BackgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var numberOfPackets = int.parse(e.UserState);

     MessageBox.Show("Percentage: " + e.ProgressPercentage );
     MessageBox.Show("Packets sent :" + numberOfPackets);  
}
```

The worker can send the percentage of completion or any other data you want through UserState.

Comment: currently my BackgroundWorker is from the main thread and check the calss who send the packets

Comment: see my updae, can you please show me how to do what you mean ?

Comment: All you have to do is typeCast. var pcapInstance = (Pcap)e.UserState;  Now you can access whole data. is this what you want?

Comment: i only want to application will not stuck if the rate of packet is so fast, the appication become gray and only when it's finish the GUI is enable again

Comment: Why are you firing the ReportProgress so frequently? Why don't you fire the event may be every n packets?

Comment: cause i want to see my progress all the time

Comment: I do not know what Pcap is doing and when it is firing the events. Also if the UI is hanging it means you are doing some time consuming tasks on the main thread.

Comment: the relevant part is several variables that bgW_ProgressChanged check all the time (number of send packets and precentage) see my update under bgW_ProgressChanged function

Comment: before firing the report progress event try this. if(pcap._numberOfSendPackets%10000 ==0) bgWoSingle.ReportProgress(progressCount, pcap);  //change the number 10000 to any thing the app is comfortable with.

Comment: the only thing i want to do is fix the issue that the application suck

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9474/discussion-between-prakash-and-user979033)

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have a PacketSender class which uses a BGWorker, and registers to it's Progress events, etc, and has a progress property or events of itself, to allow binding / listening.

Then, the PacketSender class will receive some big task to do, and will let it's BGWorker do it. Your BGWorker-Work method will be on a separate thread, and every time you call ReportProgress from within it, you will get it in your listening method in PacketSender in the main thread, and will be able to bubble it upwards to PacketSender.ProgressChanged listeners or change a ProgressChanged property of percents complete, etc.

The right way to do it would be getting the data for the task in the PacketSender ctor, and immediately start the BGWorker, to prevent having multiple tasks on the same PacketSender, or have a Start and Stop method which will check if the BGWorker is working, and will prevent multi-tasking a single PacketSender.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use BackgroundWorker here. It's new and better than defining custom events to update your progress bar. Check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).